# Execute an event in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My xaml is as under. I have an event in the xaml (mouseup) which I want to execute from another view's code behind. To explain my xaml is

```
    <Ctrls:iControl Name="test"                                        
                    ComponentCommand="{Binding SelectIconsCommand}"
    >
```

where ctrls is a different dll

```
    xmlns:Ctrls="clr-namespace:iCommon.Code.View;assembly=iCommon"
```

The problem is that the ctrls is not written very well. It has lot of code behind. How can I execute a mouseup event of ctrls's code behind from my xaml's code behind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle it in your xaml and then propagate by

```
foreignControl.RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left)
{
  RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseUpEvent,
  Source = this,
});
```